# Simple Button Event not working?

Tags: android, button

Hi I would like to ask why isn't my button not working on click I just copied my other layouts button code that works and tried creating it on my own as well but still not work?

here is my code

.java
    package com.thesis.logipic;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Menu extends Activity 
{

Button beginner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle MenuButtons) {
    super.onCreate(MenuButtons);
}

public void onClick(View v) 
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button) v;
    switch (clickedButton.getId()) 
    {

    case R.id.btnBeginner:
        setContentView(R.layout.gameplay);
        break;

    case R.id.btnLearner:
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        break;
    }
 }

}
```

.xml

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/categories" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLearner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnBeginner"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/learner_menu" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBeginner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnLearner"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/beginner_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ThesisActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.thesis.logipic.THESISACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".logipic.Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.thesis.logipic.MENU" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Gameplay"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.thesis.logipic.GAMEPLAY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Beginner"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.thesis.logipic.BEGINNER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what you r really trying to do? you have never set the content view. try some android basic tutorials from internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle MenuButtons) {
    super(MenuButtons);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.gameplay);
        }
    });
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLearner)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             setContentView(R.layout.menu);
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button beginner, learner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // Your layout

        beginner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner);
        beginner.setOnClickListener(this);

        learner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLearner);
        learner.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnBeginner:
            setContentView(R.layout.gameplay);
            break;

        case R.id.btnLearner:
            setContentView(R.layout.menu);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: it has an error when I click it unlike before it does nothing haha

Answer (score 0):

Set contentview into your onCreate method.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.menu);
```

Then add following tag into xml Button element.

```
 android:onClick="onClick"
```

**Edit**

For your ease. Its your modified code.

```
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle MenuButtons) {
   super.onCreate(MenuButtons);
   setContentView(R.layout.menu); 
  }
```

And xml

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/categories" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLearner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnBeginner"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/learner_menu"
    android:onClick="onClick" 
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBeginner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnLearner"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/beginner_menu"   
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />


</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks and btw I did the code but its force closing when I clicked the button but better than no response haha

Comment: It shows "android has stopped working unexpectedly force closing" but when I tried to put it in the 3rd layout that will show it works fine